# Sorting multidimensional Array by its Child's value

Tags: arrays, json, swift, sorting, swifty-json

I am a Swift newbie, and having difficulty in sorting a multidimensional Array.
**(Alamofire and SwiftyJSON are installed and imported)**

I want to sort the main JSON array by the highest score of each guy. 
I was able to sort ["scores"] of each with

```
     for x in 0..<JSONArray.count{
     let b  = JSONArray[x]["scores"].array?.sorted{$0["test"] < $1["test"]}
      }
```

**However, I do not know how to affect the main JSON array order.**

Here is my JSON file,

```
{"students": [{
    "id": 1,
    "profile": [{
        "name": "Kenneth",
        "age": 19
    }],
    "scores": [{
        "test": 62
    }, {
        "test": 80
    }, {
        "test": 95
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "profile": [{
        "name": "Thomas",
        "age": 12
    }],
    "scores": [{
        "test": 60
    }, {
        "test": 92
    }, {
        "test": 30
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "profile": [{
        "name": "May",
        "age": 15
    }],
    "scores": [{
        "test": 62
    }, {
        "test": 72
    }, {
        "test": 100
    }]
}]}
```

the final JSON output I want is

```
{"students": [{
    "id": 3,
    "profile": [{
        "name": "May",
        "age": 15
    }],
    "scores": [{
        "test": 100
    }, {
        "test": 72
    }, {
        "test": 62
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "profile": [{
        "name": "Kenneth",
        "age": 19
    }],
    "scores": [{
        "test": 95
    }, {
        "test": 80
    }, {
        "test": 62
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "profile": [{
        "name": "Thomas",
        "age": 12
    }],
    "scores": [{
        "test": 92
    }, {
        "test": 60
    }, {
        "test": 30
    }]
}]}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Give us an actual Swift test case to work with. We don't want to waste our time formatting your JSON into valid Swift.

Comment: Thanks for advice. This is my first post on stackoverflow asking question... and did not know the best way to bring up my question neatly... I will improve next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are sorting `scores` array in ascending order you need to sort it to descending order then set this sort array in main json Array. After that sort main Array using `scores` array's first value.

```
//Forst soret main json by max score
var jsonArray = json["students"].arrayValue

//Sort score array
for x in 0..<jsonArray.count{
    let sortedScores  = jsonArray[x]["scores"].arrayValue.sorted{$0["test"] > $1["test"]}
    jsonArray[x]["scores"] = JSON(sortedScores)
}

//Sort main array using first object of scores array
let sortedJSON = jsonArray.sorted { $0["scores"].arrayValue[0]["test"].intValue > $1["scores"].arrayValue[0]["test"].intValue }

print(sortedJSON)
```

Comment: Hey Nirav, thank you for your help! It works perfectly! I did not know I could do in this way "jsonArray[x]["scores"] = JSON(sortedScores)", to update the table.

Comment: @Superpotato Welcome mate :)

Comment: @Superpotato If my solution is works then please accept my answer. If you don't know how to accept answer on StackOverflow check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346600